# If statement ignoring zero?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

This program reads two files and stores them in two arrays. array1 is the data and array2 is the type that corresponds to it. ex array1: 183, 183, 182, 195.3, 187  array2: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 it sets the repeated numbers in the array1 to 0 and sets the corresponding number in array2 to zero. Ex: array1: 0, 0, 182, 195.3, 187 array2: 0, 0, 1, 2, 2 Then it should ignore the zeros in the for loop and calculate the sum for all the numbers of the same type. Ex: (for some reason called it mean) mean[2] = 195.3 + 187 It seems to be ignoring atleast one of the if statements which has it > .5 and going to the else statement when it encounters a zero. Any ideas?

Example data from file (not complete data), as soon as it sees 182.6000061 next to each other it sets those to zero and the corresponding number in the array2, yet it ignores one of the if statement and goes to the else statement. Output is 2822.799, 881.400, 1997.8, ect. Where the first value should be closer to 6000.

input data into array1: 182.6000061
183
182.6000061
182
177.8000031
183.3999939
183
180.6000061
147.6000061
166.6000061
168
182
181.6000061
164.1999969
180.3999939
177.3999939
177.6000061
182.6000061
182.6000061
181.6000061
179.8000031
160
177.3999939
181.3999939
183.1999969
183.1999969
182.8000031
181.3999939
179.6000061
182.1999969
183.8000031
176.8000031

input data into array2: 2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2912
2979
2979
2979
2979
2979
2979
2979
2979
2979

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    float array1[1000] = {0}, array2[1000] = {0}, mean[1000] = {0}, average[1000] = {0}, counter[1000] = {0}, range[1000] = {0}, upper[1000] = {0}, lower[1000] = {0};
    int a, h, i, r, j = 0, pos, found = 0, extrinsic[1000] = {0};
    int b=0;
    int linect = 1;
    char buf[128];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot open file for reading");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while( linect < 1000 ) 
    {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
        sscanf(buf, "%f", &array1[i]);
        //printf("Set %d - 1st: %f\n", linect, array1[i]);
        linect++;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);


    linect = 0; //reads lot data file and puts it in array2
    i = 0;
    fp = fopen("lot_numbers.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot open file for reading");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while( linect < 1000 ) 
    {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
        sscanf(buf, "%f", &array2[i]);
        // printf("Set %d - 1st: %f\n", linect, array2[i]);
        linect++;
        i++;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) //searches array sets repeated points to zero
    {
        if (array1[i] == array1[i+1])
        {
            array1[i] = 0;
            array2[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 99; i++)   //searches array
    {
        if (array2[i] > .5 && array2[i] < 50000)
        {
            if (array2[i] == array2[i+1])
            {
                if (array1[i] > .5 && array1[i] < 500){  //ignores zeros and junk data 
                    mean[j] = mean[j] + array1[i];
                    counter[j]= counter[j] + 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                average[j] = mean[j]/counter[j];
                range[j] = average[j] * 0.1;
                upper[j] = average[j] + range[j];
                lower[j] = average[j] - range[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    while (j <10){
        printf("\n%f", mean[j]);
        j++;
    }
    scanf("%d", &a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) by few macros. It is very likely you will see your problem yourself then.

Comment: Please post sample input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: updated with a portion of the input

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two different loops in your program? The first loops 999 times and the other loops 99 times.

```
for (i = 0; i < 999; i++)

for (i = 0; i < 99; i++)
```

Comment: Both should be 999 or I should change that to the linect variable, regardless that unfortunately won't effect the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as it sees 182.6000061 next to each other it sets those to zero and the corresponding number in the array2

Nope! It sets the first of those to `0` and the corresponding one in array2.
Maybe you need

```
        if (array1[i] == array1[i+1])
        {
            array1[i] = array1[i + 1] = 0;
            array2[i] = array2[i + 1] = 0;
        }
```